# MongoDB: Find documents that have array with matching elements

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Using https://voteview.com/data I’m trying to compare two Representatives voting records. I need to find documents with matching elements of the “votes” array on multiple fields. Given documents like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580940afccba0283cfbea9da"),
    "clerk_url" : "http://clerk.house.gov/cgi-bin/vote.asp?year=2013&rollnumber=11",
    "votes" : [
        {
            "icpsr" : NumberInt("21341"),
            "cast_code" : NumberInt("1"),
            "prob" : 43.6
        },
        {
            "icpsr" : NumberInt("20337"),
            "cast_code" : NumberInt("1"),
            "prob" : 99.7
        },
        {
            "icpsr" : NumberInt("20953"),
            "cast_code" : NumberInt("1"),
            "prob" : 99.4
        }
    ],
    "yea_count" : NumberInt("293"),
}
```

the following gets a documents where these two Representatives voted:

```
db.voteview_rollcalls.aggregate( [
  { $match: { $and: [ { 'votes.icpsr': 21341 }, { 'votes.icpsr': 20337 } ] } },
] );
```

How do I add criteria so that those two elements have matching cast_code? In this case, test `{votes[0].cast_code==votes[1].cast_code}` returns true, but if cast_code for icpsr=21341 is changed to 0, then I want to exclude this document.

Comment: @NeilLunn added criteria that is more restrictive than proposed duplicate, I need to match array elements to each other.

Comment: That's okay. I answered a question yesterday that covers that one. So you can have that duplicate link as well. Most things you can think of already have answers here.

Comment: Great, thanks. That one has the needed info. I was missing [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/). Sorry I couldn't find your answer posted on the same day that had no upvotes yet. I gave it one so hopefully it's easier for others to find. I had been looking for days since in the past I have always been able to find existing answers here.